# Android databinding set padding if value is true

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-databinding

I want to be able to to be able to set padding values if a boolean is true. The problem is that Android studio cannot parse the layout because it thinks 2dp is a decimal with a value of 2 and then doesn't know what to do with the p. how do I format this so that it understands i mean 2 density pixels.

Data layout:

```
<data class=".ItemBinding">
    <variable name="isGroupType" type="Boolean"/>
</data>
```

View layout(whats important):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:paddingBottom='@{isGroupType ? 2dp : 0dp}'
            android:paddingTop='@{isGroupType ? 8dp : 0dp}'
            android:paddingRight='@{isGroupType ? 2dp : 0dp}'
            android:paddingLeft='@{isGroupType ? 2dp : 0dp}'/>
```

Comment: replacing 2dp with "2dp". doesn't work.

Comment: Shot in the dark: tried, `2\dp` or just 2?

Comment: Escaping the d doesn't help. Trying the second option.

Comment: I think it is setting the padding in pixels when I just put 2. I might need a @BindingAdapter

Comment: Interesting, one more thing, just came to me, placing dp outside the curly brackets (but still within the quotes)

Comment: build error:  No resource type specified (at 'paddingBottom' with value '@{isGroupType ? 8 : 0}dp').

Comment: ehh, I tried :p, sorry. I feel you're close to a solution anyway.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Store padding value in `dimen.xml` and use it. Please keep habit to write binding string with " " (double quotes)

```
android:paddingBottom="@{isGroupType ? @dimen/padding_normal : @dimen/padding_null}"
```

and so on for other paddings also.

Comment: Why bindings should be written with " "?
If you use ' ' than you can use " " inside binding.

Comment: That's vice versa thing, if you write it in between " ", you can also use ` ` inside it.

Comment: This only works with `paddings` **NOT** with `margins`

Answer (score 29):

For anyone looking to set margins via DataBinding, you'll have to use `BindingAdapter` as well:

```
@BindingAdapter("layoutMarginBottom")
fun setLayoutMarginBottom(view: View, dimen: Float) {
    val layoutParams = view.layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = dimen.toInt()
    view.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

And your xml property will look like this:

```
app:layoutMarginBottom="@{someCondition ? @dimen/zero_dp : @dimen/twenty_dp}"
```

Comment: I would change to @BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginBottom") so it can be used with normal margin in layout

Comment: @JanuszHain yup it can be done, I personally prefer separating data binding stuff from android namespace

Comment: Java version
`    @BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginTop")
    public static void setLayoutMarginTop(View view, Float dimen) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = 
        (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.topMargin = dimen.intValue();
    }`

Comment: Accepted answer is not working for me, but this works fine. thanks for the complete answer. you saved me by putting both layout and java code. much thanks....

Answer (score 12):

Just as a heads-up this does not work with `layout_margin`'s :(

Not sure why, but think it's due to the parent layout needs to be remeasured..

Comment: Strange but true. I thought for sure I had something configured incorrectly. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: it's because it can't parse dp. It expects numbers only, which would be pixels in that case

Answer (score 3):

@Ravi's answer is correct.

But for more flexibility you can also try this:

```
@BindingAdapter({"padding", "shouldAdd"})
public static void setPadding(AppCompatImageView imageView, boolean shouldAdd, int padding){
    if (shouldAdd){
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        shouldAdd="@{isGroupType}"
        padding="@{10}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ravi's answer is good, but it's working only for padding.
If You want to simply add margin, create empty view e.g TextView with padding.

Answer (score 1):

Use a blank view

```
<View
android:layout_width = "8dp"
android:layout_height = "8dp"
>
```

Now constraint this view to the layout you want to control the visibility of .
Now disappear this view depending on the condition. would work the same as a margin

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic and ternary statements in xml-binding, but you really shouldn't. It will come back to haunt you when you're looking the usual places you have logic and don't see what's going on.
BindingAdapter for all your margin needs:

```
fun bindingSetMargins(view: View, start: Float?, top: Float?, end: Float?, bottom: Float?) {
    view.layoutParams = (view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).apply {
        start?.toInt()?.let { leftMargin = it }
        top?.toInt()?.let { topMargin = it }
        end?.toInt()?.let { rightMargin = it }
        bottom?.toInt()?.let { bottomMargin = it }
    }
}
```